# Insert HTML from SQL into textarea?

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea, parse-error

I would like to know why I am getting a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING" in my code, which pulls HTML off an MySQL database, replaces < and > with the entity (&lt ;, &gt ;) and inputs it into a textarea (CKEditor). Here is that section of the code:

```
<textarea name="editor1">
          <?php
            //QUERY DATABASE
            $query1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = '" . $id . "'";
            $resource1 = mysql_query($query1, $database);
            $result1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource1);
            $rawcode = $result['code'];\
            $code1 = str_replace("<", "&lt;", "$rawcode");
            $code = str_replace(">", "&gt;", "$code1");
            echo $code1;          
          ?>
    <!--&lt;p&gt;Create your page here.&lt;/p&gt;-->
</textarea>
```

Comment: \ behind  $rawcode = $result['code'];

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra "\" at the end of line

```
$rawcode = $result['code'];\
```

remove it

Comment: Please upvote any answers you found helpful, and mark this answer as correct if your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to escape the HTML yourself, use htmlspecialchars() instead.

Comment: what is this? The HTML is already in the DB, I just want to input it into CKEditor

Comment: Replace the 2 str_replace lines with: $code = htmlspecialchars($rawcode);

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code: 
Replace

```
 $rawcode = $result['code'];\
```

With

```
 $rawcode = $result['code'];
```

You can use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)() for your html replacement.

Replace:

```
$code1 = str_replace("<", "&lt;", "$rawcode");
$code = str_replace(">", "&gt;", "$code1");
```

With:

```
$code = htmlspecialchars($rawcode);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rawcode = $result['code'];\
```

backslash is escape char in php, and escaping $ in next line. PHP parse `$code1` as string that is not allowed here.

you shouldn't also use $rawcode, and $code1 in "", because it only slows slightly execution.

Answer (score 0):

You have two error.

The first one is the $result variable from `$rawcode = $result['code'];\`. `$result` does not exist. You called that variable `$result1`.

The second one, is the `\` at the end of `$rawcode = $result['code'];\`. You must remove it.

The end code is `$rawcode = $result1['code'];`

Another mistake I noticed, the last statement, `echo $code1;` should be `echo $code;` because `$code` contains the last change you made with `str_replace`.